# Github Pages with Sphinx generated documentation not displaying HTML correctly

Tags: github, github-pages, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have been trying to publish a Sphinx generated documentation for our repository on Github pages with the theme provided by [readthedocs.org](https://readthedocs.org/).

After a few attempts I managed to get it online by uploading the Sphinx generated HTML files in the gh-pages branch of the repository.

Obtaining this:

https://takeqontrol.github.io/qontrol_api/

Which is looking awful, erasing all the customization of the theme by Read the Docs.

Here is an example of what you see if you open the link:

[image: html as it appears in githubpages - missing all the customisation]

But if I open those HTML files on my computer the pages looks exactly how I wanted them to look.
Here is an example of how exactly the same HTML looks locally:

[image: HTML as it appears locally on browser with all the required customization]

Does anybody know what is going on? Or even point me somewhere where I can find an explanation?

All the code is available here: https://github.com/takeqontrol/qontrol_api
in the two branches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using github actions to publish documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989790/using-github-actions-to-publish-documentation)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In case it helps, I found a different solution that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65581149/6942666)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fought with this for 9 hours before figuring out that the **underscore** in the `_static` folder was causing the issue.

You need to [bypass Jekyll on github pages](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/).

To do this, add an empty `.nojekyll` to your `gh-pages` branch.  (See [example](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOS/commit/14b50b9ca0b1bb4a8263970252bcc7cdc451ed30))

Comment: An empty `.nojekyll` file don't you mean? This also worked for me under a `docs` folder if I told GitHub Pages to use `/docs` as the source to publish from.

Comment: The [`sphinx.ext.githubpages `](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/githubpages.html) Sphinx extension seems to help automate this.

Comment: You saved me a lot of trouble, I had the same issue and this fixed it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue and then found this, which solved it for me:

[Python Sphinx css not working on github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486442/python-sphinx-css-not-working-on-github-pages)

Looks like using underscores for the _sources + _static folder caused the issues. Need to rename the folders and paths using them in the html files accordingly.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your answer I tried doing that and now the page is not showing anymore. I get only the 404 error page not found. Still locally I can visualise the webpage perfectly.